# How to disable nemo's horizontal scroll

Tags: scrolling, nemo

When using the nemo file browser in icon mode (compact view) the scroll turns to horizontal rather than vertical.  For me this is very hard to work with.  If the files are in list mode you can scroll vertical to see the next list of files.  Hopefully there is a setting to allow this same type of scrolling in the alternate view.

I have spent a lot of time in all the setting options and searching the Internet.

Hopefully someone with experience can give me the setting option, or advise me that it doesn't exist and I can stop searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I happen to be using nemo, and took a quick glance at nemo's settings and nemo's settings in dconf editor.

There doesn't appear to be anything about changing the type of scrolling for compact view, so perhaps it was designed that way without an option to change it.

I would say if you've already spent at least 30 minutes searching, it would probably be better to just keep to list view and save yourself the headache of searching any longer. Possibly request this feature as well?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I'll look for a way to put in the feature request.  As far as searching and the icon view.  A half hour of searching is very much well worth the convenience.  I'd gladly put an hour of research to be able to have a vertical compact view.  I use the list and icon view for different purposes in many applications.  They aren't interchangeable.  However, if the convenience of having either isn't available in the application, I make do.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the window background and choose 'arrange items > compact layout' while in 'icon view', it is the same as if you were in 'compact view' but without the horizontal scrolling.

Comment: Hi, Rodrigo.  It appears that you're misunderstanding the question.  There is never a horizontal scroll in the icon view.  The icon view isn't a problem.  I don't know what the developers are considering the difference between the icon compact view and the compact view from the menu click of the compact view icon in the menu bar.  But as per the accepted answer, there isn't a way to remove the horizontal scroll from that particular view choice.  That particular view (the one in the question) is a total different view, of which I would use if there were a way to remove the horizontal scroll.